# Xamarin Forms app restarts instead of resume on iOS app switching

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Have a Xamarin Forms app on iOS.

When testing on physical device (iPhone), when the app is switched to background and then to foreground, it restarts.

Expected behaviour is to resume from where it left off.

Works fine on simulator.

Have tried to implement following as per this link:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/154720/forms-app-restarts-every-time-when-i-bring-it-back-from-the-background

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
base.OnSleep();
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
base.OnResume();
}
```

However, the behaviour remains same on iOS device.

Comment: Hi , maybe there is something wrong when running in physical device , and make the app restart when `OnResume` . If you can create a new created sample project which can reproduce this , share project link here . I will check that in my local site .

Comment: Checked on multiple iOS devices. Also it is working fine on Android device.

Comment: Whether occurs in a new created project ? If so ,share the sample project link here .

Comment: Also need to collect the output logs when `OnSleep()` and `OnResume()` in a physical device .

Comment: Ok. Links to any article on how to implement and collect the output logs ?

Comment: If debuging in Visual Studio , in **View -> OutPut** can see the logs(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOu9b.png) . If no useful logs in that , also can in **Tools -> iOS -> Device Logs...** to see .

Comment: Ok. Right now we are using adhoc mode to create a build and then deploy on devices using apphost.

Comment: Then could you debug that in VS ? that will be easy to check logs . Or if apphost can collect the logs when running that also will be fine .

Comment: We are using macincloud.com to debug in simulator and produce ipa - hence do not have access to the device logs. Tried with a new Xamarin Forms solution - and there the auto restart is not happening. Our Xamarin Forms solution is old, so might be some configuration issue. Whats the recommended way to upgrade the solution to latest format ?

Comment: Okey , you need to update Nuget Package of solution .Then check whehter it works .

Comment: All nuget packages already updated. But csproj file structure of newly created project seems different from that of ours, which was created around 2 years back.

Comment: Okey , for iOS platform, then you can have a look a this document .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/unified/updating-xamarin-forms-apps

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Xamarin Forms 4.6.0.800 and the issue went away.